# How can you compare frequency of letters between two words in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a word guessing game, after each guess the computer should return the frequency of letters in the right place, however it is this part that I have been unable to manage to get working. Can anyone help me?

```
import random

def guess(secret,testWord):

    return (len([(x, y) for x, y in zip(secret, testWord) if x==y]))


words = ('\nSCORPION\nFLOGGING\nCROPPERS\nMIGRAINE\nFOOTNOTE\nREFINERY\nVAULTING\nVICARAGE\nPROTRACT\nDESCENTS')
Guesses = 0

print('Welcome to the Word Guessing Game \n\nYou have 4 chances to guess the word \n\nGood Luck!')
print(words)

words = words.split('\n')
WordToGuess = random.choice(words)

GameOn = True
frequencies = []

while GameOn:

currentguess = input('\nPlease Enter Your Word to Guess from the list given').upper()
Guesses += 1
print(Guesses)

correctLength = guess(WordToGuess,currentguess)

if correctLength == len(WordToGuess):
    print('Congragulations, You Won!')
    GameOn = False
else:
    print(correctLength, '/', len(WordToGuess), 'correct') 

if Guesses >= 4:
    GameOn = False
    print('Sorry you have lost the game. \nThe word was ' + WordToGuess)
```

Comment: Do the words have varying lengths or all the same?

Comment: they are all the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `guess` function, you are printing the value, not returning it. Later, however, you try to assign something to `correctLength`. Just replace `print` by `return`, and your code should work.

---

**Update to answer question in comments:**

I think a very easy possibility (without a lot of changes to your code posted in the comment) would be to add an `else` clause, such that in case that the input is empty, you return directly to the start of the loop.

```
while GameOn:
  currentguess = input('\nPlease Enter Your Word to Guess from the list given').upper()
  if len(currentguess) <=0:
    print('Sorry you must enter a guess')
  else:
    correctLength = guess(WordToGuess,currentguess)
    if correctLength == len(WordToGuess):
      print('statement')
      GameOn = False
    elif Guesses <= 0:
      GameOn = False
      print('statement')
    else:
      Guesses = Guesses -1
      print('statement')
      print('statment')
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't realise I showed this copy, I was printing it in order to try and debug it. I've got it working now, only problem is that I can't get to make sure people aren't just entering nothing.

Comment: while GameOn:
    currentguess = input('\nPlease Enter Your Word to Guess from the list given').upper()
    if len(currentguess) <=0:
        print('Sorry you must enter a guess')
        correctLength = guess(WordToGuess,currentguess)
        if correctLength == len(WordToGuess):
            print('statement')
            GameOn = False
        elif Guesses <= 0:
            GameOn = False
            print('statement')
        else:
            Guesses = Guesses -1
            print('statement')
            print('statment')

Comment: I am not sure if I correctly understand - would it be enough to just add an `else` clause to your `if len(currentguess) <=0`? Such that all the rest of your code is only executed if the length of the input is greater zero? (Note that this does only make sure that the input length is not zero, not that it is the right length.)

Comment: Yeah I've got the (currentguess) <=0 in order to make sure that they have guessed something (rather than just an empty guess. However this is still decreasing the amount of guesses left which I do not want it to do. I only want it to decrease if it is a valid guess. Does this make sense?

Comment: See updated answer - I think it's easier to read with proper code formatting. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: That's great thanks, I'll try it out now. It was the format I was struggling with. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you!